# Sorting one xml file and get the other one to follow

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Alright. Will try to explain what I'm trying to do..

I have an XSL file that reads two xml file. Both xml files contain words. One file with English words and the other with Spanish words (same words but translated)

I have managed to print out both xml files through the xsl transformation and position them on the side of each other.

Now to my little problem. I'm using â sort on the English xml file so that the words will come out sorted alphabetically.

Now I want the Spanish words to print out similar to the English words so that you get the feeling of an translation.

I could just change the places in the xml file, but I feels like cheating.

This is my xml file in English. The Spanish one is similar just with Spanish words in it.

```
<thesaurus>
  <dictionary>
    <language>Engelska</language>
    <word type="1">Stroll</word>
    <word type="2">Tender</word>
    <word type="3">Agents</word>
    <word type="4">Partial</word>
    <word type="5">Pogotype</word>
    <word type="6">Pretend</word>
    <word type="7">Color</word>
    <word type="8">Silent</word>
    <word type="9">Foundations</word>
    <word type="10">Grain</word>
  </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

Spanish

```
  </dictionary>
        </thesaurus>    
         <word type="1">Paseando</word> <!-- Stroll-->
            <word type="2">Tierno</word>  <!--Tender -->
            <word type="3">Agentes</word>  <!--Agents -->
            <word type="4">Parcial</word>  <!--Partial -->
            <word type="5">Logo</word>  <!--Logotype -->
            <word type="6">Pretender</word>  <!-- Pretend-->
            <word type="7">Color</word>  <!--Color -->
            <word type="8">Tímido</word>  <!-- Silent-->
            <word type="9">Dimientos</word>  <!--Foundations -->
            <word type="10">Grano</word>  <!--Grain -->
           </dictionary>
            </thesaurus>
```

And this is how I'm printing out

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc1//*/*/word">
        <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc2//*/*/word">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Thanks

Comment: Felipe Otarola: This is very easy to do, however you forgot to show us the corresponding Spanish dictionary. As very few of us know Spanish, please edit the question and provide the Spanish dictionary, too. We must know which spanish word is the translation of which english word -- this relation must be in the dictionaries. Please, explain this after you have provided the Spanish dictionary.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev 
Just add the spanish Dictionary.

How do you mean that the relations must be in the dictionary ?
thanks

Comment: Felipe Otarola: I mean something that can be used to find the other language counterpart to a given word. In your case this is the `type` attribute. And you see -- as soon as you provided a sample of the Spanish dictionary, this relationship became obvious and you got a solution right away. Please, learn how to ask a good question!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="dict" select="document('dictionary.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/word">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dict/*/*/word[@type = current()/@type]"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Agents</td>
        <td>Agentes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Color</td>
        <td>Color</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Foundations</td>
        <td>Dimientos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Grain</td>
        <td>Grano</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Partial</td>
        <td>Parcial</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pogotype</td>
        <td>Logo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pretend</td>
        <td>Pretender</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Silent</td>
        <td>Tímido</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Stroll</td>
        <td>Paseando</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tender</td>
        <td>Tierno</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Input:
English words XML:

```
<thesaurus>
  <dictionary>
    <language>Engelska</language>
    <word type="1">Stroll</word>
    <word type="2">Tender</word>
    <word type="3">Agents</word>
    <word type="4">Partial</word>
    <word type="5">Pogotype</word>
    <word type="6">Pretend</word>
    <word type="7">Color</word>
    <word type="8">Silent</word>
    <word type="9">Foundations</word>
    <word type="10">Grain</word>
  </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

Spanish words XML (dictionary.xml):

```
<thesaurus>
  <dictionary>
    <word type="1">Paseando</word>
    <word type="2">Tierno</word>
    <word type="3">Agentes</word>
    <word type="4">Parcial</word>
    <word type="5">Logo</word>
    <word type="6">Pretender</word>
    <word type="7">Color</word>
    <word type="8">Tímido</word>
    <word type="9">Dimientos</word>
    <word type="10">Grano</word>
  </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

Comment: This solution, works only with one xml ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: @FelipeOtarola, You have to apply this template to English words XML. Also this template uses `document` function (in my sample it loads `dictionary.xml` with Spanish words), which loads dictionary XML.

Comment: ofcourse. I hade apply the template on both files and call both files from the xml. Solved it :)
Thank you alot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Felipe is looking for a solution where the entire thesaurus with all languages is the input XML. I am restyling Kirill's solution a little to cater for that possibility.

Input I used (including langauge value for the Spanish section) is below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[language='Engelska']/word">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="//*/*[language='Espagnol']/word[@type = current()/@type]"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thesaurus>
  <dictionary>
    <language>Engelska</language>
    <word type="1">Stroll</word>
    <word type="2">Tender</word>
    <word type="3">Agents</word>
    <word type="4">Partial</word>
    <word type="5">Pogotype</word>
    <word type="6">Pretend</word>
    <word type="7">Color</word>
    <word type="8">Silent</word>
    <word type="9">Foundations</word>
    <word type="10">Grain</word>
  </dictionary>
    <dictionary>
    <language>Espagnol</language>
    <word type="1">Paseando</word>
    <word type="2">Tierno</word>
    <word type="3">Agentes</word>
    <word type="4">Parcial</word>
    <word type="5">Logo</word>
    <word type="6">Pretender</word>
    <word type="7">Color</word>
    <word type="8">Tímido</word>
    <word type="9">Dimientos</word>
    <word type="10">Grano</word>
  </dictionary>

</thesaurus>
```

Output: same as Kirill's.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a more efficient solution using keys**. It is also more general because we produce a sorted English dictionary and a separate correspondingly - ordered Spanish dictionary, so that these two dictionaries can be used for any purpose -- either side-by-side or for translation of limited number of words:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kWordByType" match="word" use="@type"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDictSpanish" select=
  "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/spanish.xml')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfSortedEnglish">
     <thesaurus>
      <dictionary>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/language"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/word">
          <xsl:sort/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </dictionary>
     </thesaurus>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSortedEnglish"
      select="ext:node-set($vrtfSortedEnglish)"/>

 <xsl:template match="dictionary">
  <thesaurus>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vSortedEnglish/*/dictionary"/>

      <dictionary>
       <xsl:copy-of select="$vDictSpanish/*/*/language"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSortedEnglish/*/*/word"/>
      </dictionary>
     </thesaurus>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="word">
  <xsl:variable name="vType" select="@type"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vDictSpanish">
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kWordByType', $vType)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided eEnglish dictionary XML document**:

```
<thesaurus>
    <dictionary>
        <language>Engelska</language>
        <word type="1">Stroll</word>
        <word type="2">Tender</word>
        <word type="3">Agents</word>
        <word type="4">Partial</word>
        <word type="5">Pogotype</word>
        <word type="6">Pretend</word>
        <word type="7">Color</word>
        <word type="8">Silent</word>
        <word type="9">Foundations</word>
        <word type="10">Grain</word>
    </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

**and the provided Spanish dictionary XML document resides in a file at**: `c:/temp/delete/spanish.xml`:

```
<thesaurus>
    <dictionary>
        <language>Spanish</language>
        <word type="1">Paseando</word>
        <word type="2">Tierno</word>
        <word type="3">Agentes</word>
        <word type="4">Parcial</word>
        <word type="5">Logo</word>
        <word type="6">Pretender</word>
        <word type="7">Color</word>
        <word type="8">Tímido</word>
        <word type="9">Dimientos</word>
        <word type="10">Grano</word>
    </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<thesaurus>
   <dictionary>
      <language>Engelska</language>
      <word type="3">Agents</word>
      <word type="7">Color</word>
      <word type="9">Foundations</word>
      <word type="10">Grain</word>
      <word type="4">Partial</word>
      <word type="5">Pogotype</word>
      <word type="6">Pretend</word>
      <word type="8">Silent</word>
      <word type="1">Stroll</word>
      <word type="2">Tender</word>
   </dictionary>
   <dictionary>
      <language>Spanish</language>
      <word type="3">Agentes</word>
      <word type="7">Color</word>
      <word type="9">Dimientos</word>
      <word type="10">Grano</word>
      <word type="4">Parcial</word>
      <word type="5">Logo</word>
      <word type="6">Pretender</word>
      <word type="8">Tímido</word>
      <word type="1">Paseando</word>
      <word type="2">Tierno</word>
   </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

**Do Note**: The currently accepted answer performs a linear search in the Spanish dictionary for finding every matching Spanish word. Doing this for all N sorted English words is an O(N^2) algorithm (has quadratic complexity) is in unsuitable for real-size dictionaries.

The solution presented here is using a key lookup to find a matching word. This has an O(1) complexity and looking up all words is O(N) -- linear complexity. Thus, the presented solution is optimal.